Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App Accessing An Already Authenticated ASP.NET Core Web API
I have set up an ASP.NET Core Web API where I was able to successfully configure authentication where I can post my email and password to API/login and then access API/data where it shows a 401 error if I don't authenticate first, as expected.
I then set up a Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App where everything works fine if I leave the API as anonymous but as soon as I require authentication I cannot seem to find the correct way to authenticate to the API from the client or access the existing token having already authenticated to it directly above in the same browser window.
Both apps are running over Localhost over different ports.
Tutorials I have followed have included amending Program.cs, _imports.razor, Authentication.razor and installing packages but nothing has made any difference and endpoints just give a 401 error.
In the client app I also created a form to post to API/login which returns 200 if I enter the correct credentials or `401' if not but whether I authenticate correctly or not, the successful authentication is not remembered for subsequent API requests which say I am unauthenticated.
I feel like the tutorials are all covering how to build a new authentication mechanism into the client app but I only want to authenticate to the API URL and then access the other endpoints once authenticated using the same mechanism that is used
Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way but I just want to secure the information coming out of the database to the API. I have spent about 7 hours so far and seem to have got nowhere.
Any help would be really appreciated.

I have just managed to solve it by using token authentication and then using the token in the API call which then authenticates the request Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token-here") then I can make the normal API call using People = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Person>>(endpointPerson); as the request is now sent with the header so authenticates. I am not sure if this is the recommended way but it seems to do the job.

You are correct.  You need to provide the token with every API request.

Setting the bear token inside the httpclient is the right behavior, your code is right, but it need get and set the token inside each component page, you could register this httpclient with a tokenhandler which will get the token automatically and no need to set the domain.
More details, you could refer this example:
You could use BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler to process access tokens. Access tokens are only added when the request URI is within the app's base URI.
Like this:
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;

...

    builder.Services.AddHttpClient("WebAPI", 
            client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.contoso.com/v1.0"))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
    
    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
        .CreateClient("WebAPI"));

If your identity provider contains specific logic like will store the credentital inside cookie, you could create custom logic to handle it below codes to get it.
// configure client for auth interactions
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(
    "Auth",
    opt => opt.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["BackendUrl"] ?? "https://localhost:5001"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CookieHandler>();

The cookie handler, you could modify it by yourself:
/// <summary>
/// Handler to ensure cookie credentials are automatically sent over with each request.
/// </summary>
public class CookieHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Main method to override for the handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The original request.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The token to handle cancellations.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="HttpResponseMessage"/>.</returns>
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // include cookies!
        request.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);
        request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", ["XMLHttpRequest"]);

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

More details, you could refer to this article.
